# Explanation of JavaScript execution order

Tags: javascript

Hi I was sorting an array with sort and don't know why/how/the order in which JavaScript is executing the code.

code below

```
arr = ["cc", "aa", "dd", "bb"];

console.log(arr);

fun = function() {
    var re = arr;
    console.log(re);

    re = re.sort();
    console.log(re); 
};


fun();
```

I know that the sort() method changes the original array object but why when I console.log before the sort method am I not getting the original order of the array?

Can someone please explain JavaScript's execution order? I thought it executed top to bottom.

Thanks.

update: JSfiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/BPNWC/

Comment: When I copy/paste your code above into the Chrome console, I get the output you're expecting (original array order).
["cc", "aa", "dd", "bb"]
["cc", "aa", "dd", "bb"]
["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]

Comment: I am testing in JSfiddle and I get as described above and thus my original question see here. http://jsfiddle.net/BPNWC/

Answer (score 2):

your first `console.log` prints out `["cc", "aa", "dd", "bb"]`

your second `console.log` prints out `["cc", "aa", "dd", "bb"]`
because nothing changed

your third `console.log` prints out `[ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' ]`
because `sort()`; will 'sort' the array in alphabet order.

Comment: Yes that is what I was expecting to see as well, but I can't explain why it is not happening here. http://jsfiddle.net/BPNWC/

Comment: I changed your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaldim/BPNWC/1/), because JSfiddle doesn't have a console (or I can't find it). So I changed all the console.log(); to alert();

Comment: Yes it does have a console, check my fiddle. Turn on firebug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect the intermediary execution steps of the 'Array.join' method, you can pass a comparer and inspect the values it recieves:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log([a, b], arr);             // log both parameters and the array
    return (a==b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)); // return re comparison result
});
```